# anybody have the ruby GUI tools ——shoe box?

Tags: ruby

Ps:
I don't want to use tk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it's [shoes](http://github.com/shoes/shoes) your after, [nobody knows](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/shoes/shoes/nks.pdf).

Comment: That's the weirdest thing I've seen since why's poignant guide to Ruby. Does Ruby naturally lend itself to craziness?

Comment: its cause _why was a fairly prolific ruby hacker, and shoes was one of his projects :) http://viewsourcecode.org/why/

Comment: @Matt That makes sense. Or rather, it doesn't. ;)